# Disabling input box when radiobox is checked

Tags: javascript, php

I have a question regarding disabling a one input box when one of the radio box is checked and enabling them again once the radio box is unchecked. User cant choose both of the radiobox. When one is checked, the other input is disabled

This is my markup,

```
<div class="radio i-checks">
                                        <label> 
                                            <input type="radio" value="option4" name="a" id="nominalRadioBox" onchange="toggleNominalStatus();"> <i></i> Nominal &nbsp;
                                        </label>
                                        <span>
                                            <input type="text" id="nominalInputBox"> &nbsp;<span id="currency_show"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="radio i-checks">
                                        <label> 
                                            <input type="radio" value="option4" name="a" id="percentRadioBox" onchange="togglePercentStatus();"> <i></i> Percent, Specify &nbsp;
                                        </label>
                                        <span>
                                            <input type="text" id="percentInputBox"> %
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
```

and this is the javascript,

```
<script>
function toggleNominalStatus() {
        if ($('#nominalRadioBox').is(':checked')) {
            $('#percentInputBox :input').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }
    function togglePercentStatus() {
        if ($('#percentRadioBox').is(':checked')) {
            $('#nominalInputBox :input').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

somehow it doesnt work as i expected.
Please help me with this issue,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the selector:

```
        $('#percentInputBox :input').attr('disabled', true);
```

It must be

```
        $('#percentInputBox:input').attr('disabled', true);
```

because the element with ID `#percentInputBox` is of type input.

Instead it can be just:

```
        $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', true);
```

Remember, `ID` is always unique and very specific. So no need to include extra pseudo selectors or classes. It just reduces performance of selector. So just ID is enough.

So your complete code will be:

```
function toggleNominalStatus() {
    if ($('#nominalRadioBox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', false);

    }
}
function togglePercentStatus() {
    if ($('#percentRadioBox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', false);

    }
}
```

> To unselect the radio button:

This is not possible. In that case you must checkbox.

```
function toggleNominalStatus() {
    if ($('#nominalRadioBox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', false);
      $('#percentRadioBox').attr('disabled', true);



    } else {
      $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', false);
$('#percentRadioBox').attr('disabled', false);



    }
}
function togglePercentStatus() {
    if ($('#percentRadioBox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', true);
         $('#nominalRadioBox').attr('disabled', true);
          } else {
      $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', false);
   $('#nominalRadioBox').attr('disabled', false);

    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/linunahuki/2/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: it doesnt work... when i use your code. both of the radiobox can be checked but i cant unchecked them again and both input are still alive

Comment: You must use checkbox in that case. Refer http://jsbin.com/linunahuki/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with your `attr` if you use `attr` you should use `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` and if you want to use `('disabled', true)` then use `prop` attribute.
And one more you must enable other input box so user can enter value in one box at least.

```
<script>
function toggleNominalStatus() {
        if ($('#nominalRadioBox').attr("checked")) {
            $('#nominalInputBox').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
    function togglePercentStatus() {
        if ($('#percentRadioBox').attr("checked")) {
            $('#percentInputBox').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script>
function toggleNominalStatus() {
    if ($('#nominalRadioBox:checked').length) {
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#percentInputBox').val('');
    }
}

function togglePercentStatus() {
    if ($('#percentRadioBox:checked').length) {
        $('#percentInputBox').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#nominalInputBox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#nominalInputBox').val('');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will absolutely work for you..

```
<div class="radio i-checks">
    <label> 
        <input type="radio" value="option4" name="a" id="nominalRadioBox" onclick="updatetext();"> <i></i> Nominal &nbsp;
    </label>
    <span>
        <input type="text" id="nominalInputBox"> &nbsp;<span id="currency_show"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="radio i-checks">
    <label> 
        <input type="radio" value="option4" name="a" id="percentRadioBox" onclick="updatetext();"> <i></i> Percent, Specify &nbsp;
    </label>
    <span>
        <input type="text" id="percentInputBox"> %
    </span>
</div>

<script>
   function updatetext() {
       if(document.getElementById("nominalRadioBox").checked == true) {
           document.getElementById("percentInputBox").disabled = true;
           document.getElementById("nominalInputBox").disabled = false;
       }
       if(document.getElementById("percentRadioBox").checked == true) {
           document.getElementById("nominalInputBox").disabled = true;
           document.getElementById("percentInputBox").disabled = false;
       }

   }
</script>
```

What I have done over here is I have placed `onclick` function having same name `updatetext()`